# %>% .$column_name equivalent for R base pipe |>

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I frequently use the dplyr piping to get a column from a tibble into a vector as below

```
iris %>% .$Sepal.Length
iris %>% .$Sepal.Length %>% cut(5)
```

How can I do the same using the latest R built-in pipe symbol `|>`

```
iris |> .$Sepal.Length
iris |> .$Sepal.Length |>  cut(5)
Error: function '$' not supported in RHS call of a pipe
```

Comment: Base pipe does not have a data operator. The equivalent is `\(x) x$Sepal.Length`

Comment: @Oliver, thank you, I saw an answer showing how to use this.

Comment: Why oh why use `iris %>% .$Sepal.Length` rather than `iris$Sepal.Length` ?...

Comment: `cut(iris$Sepal.Length, 5)`

Comment: Have also a look at: [Pipe purely in base R ('base pipe')?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65329335/10488504)

Comment: @Cath the actual chain much longer. So after getting the vector, there's much more I want to do with it, such as using it as input to `cut()`, etc

Comment: Please provide the "longer chain" to better represent the problem.

Comment: @zx8754 It's really not relevant in the context of this question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can use `getElement()`.

```
iris |> getElement('Sepal.Length') |> cut(5)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer too, it's the most concise so far. I wait for a while to see if there's another answer. Thanks again

Comment: Or `iris |> with(Sepal.Length)`

Answer (score 21):

In base pipe no placeholder is provided for the data that is passed in the pipe. This is one difference between `magrittr` pipe and base R pipe. You may use an anonymous function to access the object.

```
iris |> {\(x) x$Sepal.Length}()
```

Comment: I see, that's longer that I expected, but great to know. Thanks @Ronak

Comment: Is wrapping in parethesis iris |> (\(x) x$Sepal.Length)() |> cut(5)
like this is the same as using {}?

Comment: I have not used parenthesis like this but I think it works the same way.

Comment: @jpdugo17 The only differences are that `{}` can contain multiple expressions (separated by newline or, `;`), and that it preserves a value's auto-printing visibility. … And of course it uses visually distinct delimiters, which can make nested expressions (as in this case) more readable.

Answer (score 13):

Since *R 4.3.0*, as an experimental feature, the placeholder `_` can now also be used in the rhs of a forward pipe `|>` expression as the first argument in an extraction call, such as `_$coef`. More generally, it can be used as the head of a chain of extractions, such as `_$coef[[2]]`.

```
iris |> _$Sepal.Length

iris |>  _[["Sepal.Length"]]
```

For more then one column:

```
iris |> _[c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")]
```

---

Before *4.3.0* was the direct usage of `$` in `|>` [disabled](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e3b297a64f932d402dc59727c088386cae6a8112/src/main/names.c#L1007). If the call of `$` or other disabled functions in `|>` are still needed, an option, beside the creation of a function is to use `$` via the function `::` as `` base::`$` ``  or place it in brakes `(`$`)`:

```
iris |> (`$`)("Sepal.Length")

iris |> base::`$`("Sepal.Length")

iris |> (\(.) .$Sepal.Length)()

fun <- `$`
iris |> fun(Sepal.Length)
```

This will also work in cases where more than one column will be extracted.

```
iris |> (`[`)(c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length"))
```

Another option can be the use of a *bizarro pipe* `->.;`. Some call it a [joke](https://win-vector.com/2016/12/13/magrittrs-doppelganger/) others [clever use of existing syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65329845/10488504).

```
iris ->.; .$Sepal.Length
```

This creates or overwrites `.` in the `.GlobalEnv`. `rm(.)` can be used to remove it. Alternatively it could be processed in `local`:

```
local({iris ->.; .$Sepal.Length})
```

In this case it produces two same objects in the environment `iris` and `.` but as long as they are *not modified* they point the the same address.

```
tracemem(iris)
#[1] "<0x556871bab148>"
tracemem(.)
#[1] "<0x556871bab148>"
```

Comment: To clarify, now we have 2 same objects in the environment `iris` and `.`

Comment: Great, but the Bizzarro Pipe article states that though this works, it was intended as a "joke" and should not be used in practice.

Comment: @tpetzoldt At least *g-grothendieck* describes it as [clever use of existing syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65329845/10488504)

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks for the comment. I have added that these objects *point the the same address as long as they are not modified*.

Comment: @GKi “clever” ≠ “good”. I hope nobody *actually* recommends using this in practice.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the comment. But why should it not be recommended? I asked a [question on this topoc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67868289/10488504).

Answer (score 5):

Interesting example and great answers, let me add another version: I use usually `select`and then `unlist` in such cases. This follows the "[speaking R](https://youtu.be/ckW9sSdIVAc)" paradigm and works same with both operators `%>%` and `|>`:

```
library("dplyr")
iris %>% select(Sepal.Length) %>% unlist() %>% cut(5)

iris |> select(Sepal.Length) |> unlist() |> cut(5)
```

Note that `select` is from **dplyr** and `pull` brought in from @jpdugo17 is even better.

If we use usual "base R" indexing, it is also short and works in both worlds:

```
iris[["Sepal.Length"]] |> cut(5)

iris$Sepal.Length |> cut(5)
```

and thanks to the comment of @zx8754 one can of course also use base R without any pipes

```
cut(iris$Sepal.Length, 5)
```

... but I think that the OP just wanted to point out differences in piping. I guess that it is to be applied in a bigger context and `iris` is only an example.

Comment: iris |> subset(TRUE, Sepal.Length) |> unlist() |> cut(5) also does the trick while remaining in base R.

Comment: Hmm. Honestly I can’t see the benefit of the `select(…) |> unlist()` idiom. It’s strictly more verbose than using `with(…)` or `pull(…)`. What am I missing?

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's just in case that for whatever reason only base functions are available. And because tidyverse already has magrittr's pipe that in my opinion it's much better and preferred.

Comment: @jpdugo17 Well in that case just use `with`.

Comment: `with` is of course fine, but as I understood the OP, the question was mainly motivated by exploring differences between `%>%` and `|>`.  My personal impression is, that this is highly needed to gain more understanding how to use pipes in the future.

Answer (score 4):

This is also an option:

```
iris |> dplyr::pull(Sepal.Length) |> cut(5)
```

Edit:

I wonder why calling a function with backticks isn't allowed.

```
iris |> `[`(, 'Sepal.Length')
#>Error: function '[' not supported in RHS call of a pipe
```

As pointed out by @Hugh, backticks are allowed but some functions are not.

Here's the blacklisted functions list extracted from [wch Github](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e3b297a64f932d402dc59727c088386cae6a8112/src/main/names.c#L1023)

```
"if", "while", "repeat", "for", "break", "next", "return", "function",
"(", "{",
"+", "-", "*", "/", "^", "%%", "%/%", "%*%", ":", "::", ":::", "?", "|>",
"~", "@", "=>",
"==", "!=", "<", ">", "<=", ">=",
"&", "|", "&&", "||", "!",
"<-", "<<-", "=",
"$", "[", "[[",
"$<-", "[<-", "[[<-",
0
```

Comment: If we can use pull from dplyr why not pipe?  The question suggests a case working in baseR only

Comment: @jpdugo17 thanks for this answer, I can see myself using this solution as well because I want to avoid using the `'...'` often. ButI think the `getElement()` solution is closer to pure `baseR` solution. Thanks again

Comment: It's not the backtick, but the `[` operator that is blacklisted. You can see the blacklist in names.c : https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e3b297a64f932d402dc59727c088386cae6a8112/src/main/names.c#L1023

Comment: @Hugh The fact that the pipe code prohibits using these names is increeeedibly annoying, and doesn’t seem to have any good reason.

Comment: @KonradRudolph there are good reasons but they’re not easy to explain. See Luke’s discussion on the mailing list

Comment: @Hugh Actually I can’t find that explanation. I’m *fairly* sure I’ve read all relevant threads. There’s one where Luke says it’s important to remove ambiguity but then [later](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2020-December/080213.html) he walks back on this. In particular, *there’s simply no ambiguity* when requiring trailing parentheses after a function call (as is currently thankfully the case). I’ve been using a custom pipe operator since before ‘magrittr’ existed and I’ve spent a lot of time thinking about implementations and I can’t think of a valid reason for this behaviour.

Comment: (Of course claiming I have experience in the subject doesn’t make me immune from mistakes. It’s entirely possible that there’s a compelling reason I’m overlooking. But I can’t find that reason on r-devel.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is closed. Other Base R solutions where we use symbol name instead of the character name might include:

```
 iris |>
    with(Sepal.Length)


 iris |>
    subset(select = Sepal.Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [R 4.2.0](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html), you can use `_` as a placeholder for `|>`. Because "[functions in rhs calls [can] not be syntactically special](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pipeOp.html)", you cannot use `$` directly, so you have to define the function with another name first, and then use the placeholder and the column name:

```r
set <- `$`
iris |> set(x = _, Sepal.Length)
```