# Use base R pipe in conditional dplyr chain

Tags: r

I am wondering how to use the base `|>` pipe in place of tidyverse's `%>%` in a situation where there are conditional elements of a dplyr chain. When I try to following code with `|>`, I get an error:

```
Error: function '{' not supported in RHS call of a pipe
```

Example with Tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

condition = FALSE

mtcars %>%
  { if(condition == TRUE)
    mutate(., mpg = mpg*1000)
    else . }
```

Example with base R pipe (causes error):

```
mtcars |>
  { if(condition == TRUE)
    mutate(., mpg = mpg*1000)
    else . }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call it via an unnamed function. This is needed as you are using the placeholder on two positions.

```
mtcars |>
  {\(.) if(condition == TRUE)
    mutate(., mpg = mpg*1000)
    else . }()
```

Have also a look at [What are the differences between R's new native pipe `|>` and the magrittr pipe `%>%`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/).

Comment: That works, but it's so....ugly ;)

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Does the Bizarro pipe ->.; have disadvantages making it not recommended for use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67868289/) as another possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Can you put the condition inside of `mutate`?

```r
mtcars |>
  mutate(mpg = if (condition) mpg*1000 else mpg)
#                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks. It works in this example but I actually have a few functions chained within the conditional

Comment: I understand, it was worth mentioning

Answer (score 1):

Try `within`.

```
mtcars |> within(mpg[condition] <- mpg[condition]*1e3)
```

### Demo

```
condition <- FALSE
mtcars |> 
  within(mpg[condition] <- mpg[condition]*1e3) |>
  head(3)
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1

condition <- TRUE
mtcars |> 
  within({
    mpg[cond] <- mpg[cond]*1e3
    am[cond] <- am[cond]*-999
  }) |>
  head(3)
#                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs   am gear carb
# Mazda RX4     21000   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0 -999    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21000   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0 -999    4    4
# Datsun 710    22800   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1 -999    4    1
```