# Ways to select multiple columns in base R using the native pipe |>?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

What are good ways to select multiple columns of a data frame in base R using the native pipe |>? (i.e., without the tidyverse/dplyr to reduce external dependencies).

If we have the data frame

```
dtf <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9)
```

then we can select columns b and c with

```
> dtf[c("b", "c")]
  b c
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

An elegant way to do this in the tidyverse with the native pipe is

```
> dtf |> dplyr::select(b, c)
  b c
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

My best base R attempt with the native pipe was

```
> dtf |> subset(select = c("b", "c"))
  b c
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

A more concise (but failed attempt) was

```
> dtf |> `[`(c("b", "c"))
Error: function '[' not supported in RHS call of a pipe
```

Are there better ways to do this that I'm missing?

Note: If you wanted only a single column and were okay with dropping into a vector, then `getElement` could be used:

```
> dtf |> getElement("b")
[1] 4 5 6
```

Comment: Something more elegant than the canonical use of `subset`? Nope, that's the best way in base R. (BTW, you can do `X <- \`[\`'; dtf |> X(c("b", "c"))` as a workaround for base R not wanting you to use `\`[\`` in a pipe like that. Suggested by a  comment in [data.table#4872](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4872#issuecomment-845022020).)

Comment: Have a look here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67799890/column-name-equivalent-for-r-base-pipe>

Comment: See: [Pipe purely in base R ('base pipe')?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65329335/10488504)

Answer (score 5):

Experimental feature since R 4.3.0. The placeholder `_` can now also be used in the rhs of a forward pipe `|>` expression as the first argument in an extraction call.

```
dtf |> _[c("b", "c")]
#  b c
#1 4 7
#2 5 8
#3 6 9
```

Alternatively put brackets around:

```
dtf |> (`[`)(c("b", "c"))
#  b c
#1 4 7
#2 5 8
#3 6 9
```

or call it over `::`:

```
dtf |> base::`[`(c("b", "c"))
#  b c
#1 4 7
#2 5 8
#3 6 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
dtf |> (\(x) `[`(x, c("b", "c")))()
#  b c
#1 4 7
#2 5 8
#3 6 9
```

You must use the anonymous function `\(x)` and pass it as an argument to `[`. Don't forget to end with the parenthesis `()`.

Comment: Thanks @Rui for clarifying how to do this with the new anonymous function syntax. Very instructive.